# How to interface EOSIO smart contract with android dapp

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosiocpp

I have been going through this [To do Dapp tutorial](https://steemit.com/eos/@eos-asia/part-2-building-a-to-do-list-with-eos-or-working-with-persistent-data-in-eos) how can I interface/build an android app for this?.

Comment: Maybe you should add some information about what languages you are experienced with.

Comment: Using Android SDK  and Java

Answer (score 0):

Use eos.js and rpc to interract with your SC

Answer (score 0):

The eos-jvm library provides all you need for interacting with EOS from Android.
https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm